# Add text for parent div range 5 to 9 only

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="parent1"></div>
<div id="parent2"></div>
<div id="parent3"></div>
<div id="parent4"></div>
<div id="parent5"></div>
<div id="parent6"></div>
<div id="parent7"></div>
<div id="parent8"></div>
<div id="parent9"></div>
<div id="parent10"></div>
<div id="parent11"></div>
```

if i use this it will pass all div

```
$("[id^=parent]").text('hai');
```

i want only 5 to 9 th div parent text have "hai" text

Any Ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with looping from 5 to 9 while selecting the `div` individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)**:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of
>   indices.

```
$("[id^=parent]").slice(4,9).text('hai');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pJ8b/)**

or you can also use **[:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)** selector along with **[:lt()](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** selector:

```
$("[id^=parent]:gt(3):lt(5)").text('hai');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pJ8b/1/)**

Comment: ok how can i do write onclick for those id from 5 to 9 can u explain?

Comment: $("[id^=parent]").slice(4,9).click(function() {

Answer (score 2):

```
var i=0;
for (i=5;i<=9;i++)
   $("#parent"+i).text('hai');
```

Working fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/6B2Qd/

Comment: i don't want for loop

Comment: What's wrong with looping from 5 to 9 while selecting the div individually?   ,A user with 5000+ repu. asked you.

Comment: beacuse All div are occurs dynamically - pratik

Comment: @sudhar , Then what ? $("[id^=parent]").slice(4,9).text('hai');   Here also , you set 4,9 statically

Comment: @sudhar ,Anyway for dynamic way , you can set for(i=StartDynamicVal;i<=EndDynamicVal;i++) And here you can set These 2 values dynamic.Do u get it?